# JavaScript and Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I'm trying to load a bunch of resources async using promises with `Jimp.js`. The loading code is a disaster trying to chain it all, and I need a cleaner solution.

What I came up with was below. This obviously doesn't do anything, because it's junk code, but I need to know if there was a failure loading any of the resources, and I need to know when they completed.

```
function doSomething(asdf) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //console.log("It is done.");
    // Succeed half of the time.
    var x = Math.random();    
    if (x > .5) {
      resolve(["SUCCESS",asdf,x])
    } else {
      reject(["Failure",asdf,x])
    }
  });
}



func();

function func() {
    //Imagine a is actually an image loaded by doSomething
    var a=null;  doSomething("1").then(function (data) {a = data;},
            (err) => {throw new err;});
    //Imagine b is a font resource.
    var b=null;  doSomething("2").then(function (data) {b = data;},
            (err) => {throw new err;});

    Promise.all([a, b]).then(function() {
            console.log(a);
            console.log(b);
            //Then here I expect everything to be correct, and continue on with the next function.
    }, 
    (err) => {console.log('Oops:' + err);}).
     catch( (err) => {console.log('Oops:' + err);});
}
```

For some reason, this never outputs **"Oops"**.

Here is a fail output:

> [ 'SUCCESS', '1', 0.756461151774289 ]
>   null

What am I missing here?

*Update*

I took part of an answer I received and changed it so that it behaves exactly as I wanted:

```
function func() {
    var a=doSomething("1").then(function (data) {a = data;});
    var b=doSomething("2").then(function (data) {b = data;});

    Promise.all([a, b]).then(function() {
            console.log(a);
            console.log(b);
    }, 
    (err) => {console.log('Reject:' + err);});
}
```

*Update*

Here is the actual code I'm using that's working great now:

```
LoadResources() {
    var ps = [];
    console.log("Loading now");

    ps.push(jimp.read(this.ipath+"c4box.png").then(function (image) {obj.imBox = image;}));
    ps.push(jimp.read(this.ipath+"red.png").then(function (image) {obj.imRed = image;}));
    ps.push(jimp.read(this.ipath+"green.png").then(function (image) {obj.imGreen = image;}));
    ps.push(jimp.read(this.ipath+"top.png").then(function (image) {obj.imTop = image;}));
    ps.push(jimp.read(this.ipath+"bot.png").then(function (image) {obj.imBot = image;}));
    ps.push(jimp.loadFont(jimp.FONT_SANS_32_WHITE).then(function (font) {obj.imFont = font;}));

    Promise.all(ps).then( () => {
            obj.loaded = true;
            obj.imBg = new jimp(512, 576, function (err, image) { });
            console.log("Actually loaded now.");                       
            obj.StartGame();
    });
    console.log("Loading commands complete");            
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use those `a` and `b` variables for the images. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572) for the values that would be passed into `Promise.all`). You need to use variables for the promise objects that `doSomething()` returns. The images will only be available inside the `then` callback - `Promise.all` creates a promise that fulfills with an array of the results:

```
function func() {
    // aPromise is a promise for an image loaded by doSomething
    var aPromise = doSomething("1");
    // bPromise is a promise for a font resource.
    var bPromise = doSomething("2");

    Promise.all([aPromise, bPromise]).then(function([a, b]) {
//                                                  ^^^^^^
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        // Then here I expect everything to be correct, and continue on with the next function.
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('Oops:' + err);})
    });
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, if the data needs to be formatted, or only specific parts need to be extracted, you can keep the `.then()` on the `.doSomething()` call, like so:  `aPromise = doSomething("1").then(function (data) { return data.subData; }`. The important piece is the `return` statement inside the `.then()`, so it can continue to be chained

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to var a = doSomething()...  and it's perfect.  I will update the question for the future.

Comment: @CharlesW No, don't use `.then(function (data) {a = data;});`

Comment: The reason that I did that was that *a* and *b* are class variables for storing images for later use.  This is a persistent project in node.js.   Could you further explain why 
I should not?

Comment: @CharlesW Those variables are useless because you never know when you can already use them or not (if the promise was not fulfilled (yet)). Instead, store the promise object itself on your class instance.

Comment: @CharlesW Or if it is about constructing/initialising the `obj`, just do that inside the `then` callback on the `all` promise. You won't use the `obj` while it is incomplete anyway.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, it's about getting the object back.  You can see the final code in the last update of the question.

Comment: @CharlesW Yes, but you really should use `Promises.all([read("boxpath"), read("redpath"), read("greenpath"), …]).then([box, red, green, …]) => { obj.imBox = box; obj.imRed = red; obj.imGreen = green; … })`. And preferably also put the `var obj = new …` inside that callback

Comment: I disagree.  I want the whole object contained in one line of code.  I don't want to have to remember to type it in 3 places.  I'll be adding objects.  It's supposed to be readable code and easy to maintain.  Also, the new object() in there is instant, I can't add it to the array, it doesn't support that in my version.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Promise.all([a, b])
```

Cause `a` and `b` are `null` as you set them to `null`. Therefore Promise.all won't wait at all, it will resolve one tick afterwards, and as `a` and `b` get resolved / rejected very fast, that might has happened before and `a` / `b` gets set before it reaches

```
 console.log(a)
```

which will log the right results *sometimes*, but thats based on chance.

Answer (score 1):

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) returns a promise and this promise contains the result of the previous promises

```
Promise.all([ doSomething('1'), doSomething('2')])
  .then(results => {
    // results is an array which contains the result of the previous promises
    const [a, b] = results
  }).catch(err => console.log('Oops:' + err))
```